# espeak cannot work in rc.local (ubuntu)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I need to use `espeak` at the start of system. So I add the following command to **/etc/rc.local**

```
espeak "hello" >>/etc/start.log 2>&1
```

Howerver, it does't work and logs the following error:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:606:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1029:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:606:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1029:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1029:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
Expression 'paInvalidSampleRate' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2048
Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_InitialConfigure( &self->playback, outParams, self->primeBuffers, hwParamsPlayback, &realSr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2722
......
(more)
```

Howerver, if I put the command to bash profile, everything will be fine(but I don't want to put it here for other purpose)
I tried to find the problem and considered the audio hardware may not be initialized at the booting time.
So I write a simple python script

```
import time, os
time.sleep(300)
os.system("espeak 'hello 123'")
```

and add to  **/etc/rc.local**

```
nohup python3 -u /home/xxx/test.py >> /home/xxx/log.log 2>&1 &
```

Unfortunately, I got the **same error**. I also tried to start a simple http server by a python script, and call `os.system("espeak 'hello 123'")` at a certain request but I got the **same error**. I also tried this in another PC, but I also got the **same error**

It's really ridiculous and unbelievable. Can anyone help me figure out the problem?

(sorry for bad English)

Comment: Depends on details of your system's ALSA configuration and sound hardware, and you've provided no such details whatsoever in the question.

Comment: Insofar as the problem is one of not having modules loaded when `rc.local` runs, by the way, I'd tend to suggest *loading the modules* rather than just putting in a big sleep. (Likewise, if the issue is one of needing the PulseAudio daemon up, an easy answer is to, well, *actually start it*).

Comment: If the issue is that you aren't running a system-wide PulseAudio instance at all, btw, see https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/SystemWide/ -- note the documentation regarding reasons (security-related and otherwise) why this isn't suggested, so you're better off configuring ALSA to communicate directly with the hardware.

Comment: (Also, inasmuch as "how do I make my audio drivers work without a user session running?" is the question, there's an argument for that to be more topical over on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) than here).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.